Export and import database in UTF8
I'm migrating a Moodle server in Spanish. I need use tick marks. I have export and import database.
mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -u root -p moodle > moodle.sql
mysql -u root -p --default-character-set=utf8mb4 moodle < C:\Temp\moodle.sql
When I open the .sql file on notepad++, it is in UTF16 (Unicode). I changed it to UTF8 and saved the file. But when I import and launch, a query words with tick marks appears with errors.
How can I be sure that my file is encoded in UTF8?

The database needs to be configured for UTF-8. Most databases did not have UTF-8 support until a few years ago.  See the following for the DML commands to alter the database: https://stackoverflow.com/a/202246/175990
